How to find out which photos are taking up space on my iPhone
I have iCloud Photo Library enabled which offloads large media files from my iPhone to the cloud. I have 2 TB of iCloud storage. However, it seems like on my phone, I have around 25 GB of media file downloaded, which constitutes around a quarter of the storage space I have.

I would like to get rid of some of these large media files as they keep running out of space on my phone and can't install updates. However, I can't figure out which media files are taking up these 25 GB of space—most of my media in the photos app seems to be offloaded to the cloud, and there's no way to filter which files are offloaded from the app.
Is there a good way for me to find out which media files are taking up all the space on my iPhone so that I can delete them?

It is possible to show the biggest videos by size in your photos library in shortcuts.app. But i am not sure if it will consider whether the video is on-device or evicted...

That might have done the trick. I selected a couple of videos and checked the file size using shortcuts, and they were all under 1 MB, presumably the previews of the media files. If I could improve the shortcut to look through my whole library and sort by size, I could find the worst offenders and trim down my photo library that way. Wish there was an app that could do this for me. (There was one that showed filesizes, but it's slipping my memory atm...)
